# Why I cannot post data in express with nodes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below is my code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var login = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({
  secret: "HelloExpressSESSION",
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

login.get('/login_page', function(req, res){
  if(req.session.logined) {
      res.send('<a href=\"/logout\">Logout</a>');
      res.end();
      return;
   }

res.send('<form action=\"/login\" method=\"POST\">' +
    '<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\">' +
    '<br/>' +
    '<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\">' +
    '<br/>' +
    '<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Log In\">' +
    '</form>');
  res.end();
});

login.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  if(req.body.username != 'user' || req.body.password != '123456789') {
      res.send('Wrong information!');
      res.end();
      return;
  }

req.session.logined = true;
  console.log("hi");
  res.redirect('/login_page');
  res.end();
});

login.post('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.session.logined = false;
  res.redirect('/login');
  res.end();
});

app.use('/', login);
app.listen(12345);
```

Everything is ok, I can input user/123456789 and then show Logout link.
However, after I click Logout link, it shows "Cannot GET /logout" on the page.

Did I missing something?

Comment: logout is a POST route, you can't use GET to access it unless you change it to a GET route.

Comment: can explain more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: POST !== GET, not sure if i can get much simpler than that without actually writing the code out.

Comment: Thanks.I know where is the problem now. The link only generate GET request. so I have to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a route for a `POST` operation for `/logout`.  Clicking on a link would generate a `GET` request, not a `POST`.

Perhaps you mean to change this to a GET handler like this - change `login.post()` to `login.get()`:

```
login.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.session.logined = false;
  res.redirect('/login');
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.